# How to convert scala List in to Map

Tags: scala

I saw some stackoverflow questions but I am curious if an shorter way to convert List into Map (I am new to scala)

**Input** -

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

**required Output** -

```
Map(1->2, 3->4, 5->6)
```

does scala have any shorter way to convert list into map

Comment: Can you link to those other questions you saw?

Comment: What do you mean with shorter? What alternatives you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not super-short:

```
List(1,2,3,4).grouped(2).collect{ case List(k,v) => k -> v }.toMap
```

Comment: It will drop last item if `(list.length%2) !=0`. It is somehow

Comment: If you want to do something with that extra element for an odd entry size, you can add a `case List(x) => ??? ` to produce the mapping that would be appropriate.